# Make a dictionary from list and after split in two

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of names. My task is to make a dictionary from the list and after divide it into two by sex. I understand how to make a one dictionary but how to divide it by two and after return them. 
This is what I've done so far:

```
def to_dictionary(names: list) -> dict:
    """ Make a dictionary from a list of names."""
    dct = dict()
    for i in names:
        dct[i] = names.count(i)
    return dct


def to_sex_dicts(names_dict: dict) -> tuple:
    """Divide the names by sex to 2 different dictionaries."""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    example_names = ("Kate:F\n" * 1000 + "Alex:M\n" * 800 + "Marina:F\n" * 600 + "Artyom:M\n" * 400).rstrip("\n").split("\n")
    people = to_dictionary(example_names)
    print(people)
    male_names, female_names = to_sex_dicts(people)
    print(male_names)
    print(female_names)
```

Comment: Start by looping over your `people` keys which are in the format of "NAME:GENDER" and split them on ":", then go from there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a dict comprehension i.e

```
def to_sex_dicts(names_dict: dict) -> tuple:
    """Divide the names by sex to 2 different dictionaries."""
    m = {i : names_dict.get(i) for i in names_dict.keys() if ':M' in i}
    f = {i : names_dict.get(i) for i in names_dict.keys() if ':F' in i}
    return m,f

male_names, female_names = to_sex_dicts(people)
print(male_names)
{'Artyom:M': 400, 'Alex:M': 800}

print(female_names)
{'Marina:F': 600, 'Kate:F': 1000}
```

Comment: I have a question what is the difference between this brackets () and {}? For example can i write m = (i : names_dict.get(i) for i in names_dict.keys() if ':M' in i)?

Comment: `() `= Tuple and `{}` is dictionary. You can use key:value inside a tuple its limited only to dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

This simple loop does the trick for me

```
def to_sex_dicts(names_dict: dict) -> tuple:
    females = []
    males = []
    for k in names_dict:
        if k.endswith(':F'):
            females.append(k)
        elif k.endswith(':M'):
            males.append(k)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Illegal Name")
    return males, females
```